# How I can test ngrx effects using jasmine marbles?

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, ngrx, jasmine-marbles

I can't test NgRx effects. Can you help me?

Friends, help me please. I want test some effect, but i can't. I get error "Expected $[0].notification.value.payload to be a kind of Object, but was User({ name: '1212', roles: [ 'somerole' ] })".
I don't understand what wrong.

effect:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private rootService: RootService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
  }

  @Effect()
  authUser$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.FETCHING),
    map((action: authActions.Fetching) => action.payload),
    switchMap((paylod: UserRequest) => this.rootService.login(paylod)
        .pipe(
          map((value) => {
            const {sub, authorities} = value;
            this.router.navigate(['/customers-list']);
            return new authActions.Success(new User(sub, authorities));
          }),
          catchError(() => of(new authActions.Fail('wrong username or password')))
        )
    )
  );
}
```

spec:

```
describe('AuthEffects', () => {
  let effects: AuthEffects;
  let rootService: jasmine.SpyObj<RootService>;
  let actions: Observable<any>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        RootService,
        AuthEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions),
        {
          provide: RootService,
          useValue: {
            login: jasmine.createSpy()
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    effects = TestBed.get(AuthEffects);
    rootService = TestBed.get(RootService);
  });

  it('should work', () => {
    const userRequest: UserRequest = {
      name: '1212',
      password: 'alsj'
    };
    const userResponse: UserResponse = {
      sub: '1212',
      authorities: ['somerole']
    };
    const editedUser: User = {
      name: '1212',
      roles: ['somerole']
    };
    const action = new authActions.Fetching(userRequest);
    const completion = new authActions.Success(editedUser);

    actions = hot('-a', {a: action});
    const response = cold('-a|', {a: userResponse});
    rootService.login.and.returnValue(response);
    const expected = cold('--b', {b: completion});

    expect(effects.authUser$).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```

I tried make it according some example, but anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a minor change to how you are setting the expect block in test. Try the following:

```
effects.authUser$.subscribe(actionSent => {
 expect(actionSent).toBeObservable(expected)
})
```

instead of

```
expect(effects.authUser$).toBeObservable(expected);
```

I hope that will work for you.

Comment: Good try, but I got error: "Uncaught TypeError: actual.subscribe is not a function thrown"

Comment: I get the same error, but can not find / do not understand the problem. Do you know whats actially the problem in this case?

Comment: This won't work as a subscribed Observable is not an Observable anymore. You can subscribe and check then with "toBe", yes, but not with "toBeObservable". And then you also can't check the returned action. Marble testing is actually there to not need a subscription. I have the same problem that the typing gets lost. I'd really like to have something like a type assumption for marbles :(.

Answer (score 0):

seems like constructor break this. If I change effect code without constructor - its works

```
  @Effect()
  authUser$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.FETCHING),
    map((action: authActions.Fetching) => action.payload),
    switchMap((paylod: UserRequest): any => this.rootService.login(paylod)
        .pipe(
          map((value: UserResponse) => {
            const {sub, authorities} = value;
            return new authActions.Success({
              name: sub,
              roles: authorities
            });
          }),
          catchError(() => of(new authActions.Fail('wrong username or password')))
        )
    )
  );
```

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, but I've edited out the last bit where you ask where you went wrong. You shouldn't ask questions in answers as things quickly get messy and it becomes difficult to figure out what answer relates to what other answer. If you still want to know what went wrong, you should post another question (link to this one for reference). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22871604)